# WriterNotOpenException thrown when using AsyncItemWriter with FlatFileItemWriter as delegate

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am getting WriterNotOpenException when using FlatFileItemWriter with AsyncItemWriter as delegate shown as the following:

```
<bean id="partFile" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource" scope="step">
        <constructor-arg value="#{stepExecutionContext[resourceName]}" />
    </bean>
<bean id="partItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter"
        parent="abstractFlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
        <property name="resource" ref="partFile" />

    </bean>
<bean id="partItemWriterAsync" class="org.springframework.batch.integration.async.AsyncItemWriter">
        <property name="delegate" ref="partItemWriter" />
    </bean><batch:step id="partFeedGenerationStep">
        <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk reader="partItemReader" 
                processor="partItemProcessorAsync"
                writer="parttemWriterAsync" commit-interval="10" />
</batch:step>
```

Same step works fine if I step it in synchronous mode as the following,

```
<batch:step id="partitionFeedGenerationStep">
        <batch:tasklet>
<batch:chunk reader="rwaPartitionCachePaginatedItemReader" 
                processor="rwaRsCompositeItemProcessor"
                writer="parItemWriter" commit-interval="10" />
</batch:step>
```

EXCEPTION:
AbstractStep  Encountered an error executing step partFeedGenerationStep in job etl.dstream.optima.rwa.MasterJob [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-6]
org.springframework.batch.item.WriterNotOpenException: Writer must be open before it can be written to
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.write(FlatFileItemWriter.java:255)

Any suggestion to resolve this?

Comment: Where is the relationship to [tag:batch-file]?

Comment: if I understood correctly, you meant this:

Comment: <batch:job id="partFeedGenerationJob">
  <batch:step id="existingBaseFinalPartitionFeedGenerationStep">
   <batch:partition step="partitionFeedGenerationStep" partitioner="stepPartitioner">
    <batch:handler grid-size="5" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
   </batch:partition>
  </batch:step>
 </batch:job>

Answer (score 0):

In spring-batch-integration v3.x `AsyncItemWriter` implements `ItemWriter`, not `ItemStreamWriter` so it is not compatible with `FlatFileItemWriter`.  This problem has been fixed in v4.x, but actually only a v4.0.0.M3 is available, so I have taken just [the source of `AsyncItemWriter`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/master/spring-batch-integration/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/integration/async/AsyncItemWriter.java) from github and added it to my source code.  It works.  When a definitive v4.x will be available I will upgrade and remove the "custom" class.